# Reading EXIF data to textView in new Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, exif

I've been able to pass a selected image from grid view to a new full screen activity.  I am now trying to capture the EXIF data from the image and pass it into a new activity.

The first activity of passing the int from grid view seems to be working fine.

```
public class test extends Activity {
public static int pos;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.thumb);



    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.thumbgridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new tImageAdapter(this));


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(test.this,test2.class);
                pos=position;
                intent.putExtra("pos", pos);
                startActivity(intent);
            finish();




        }
    });}
}
```

The second activity which displays the full image seems to be working fine.

```
public class test2 extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.full);


        Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefull);

        int pos = bundle.getInt("pos");
        bundle.getFloat(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);

        tImageAdapter obj = new tImageAdapter(this);
        image.setImageResource(obj.tThumbIds[pos]);

        Button bDIR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDIR);
        bDIR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(test2.this,Direct.class);                   

                intent.putExtra(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            finish();







            }


        });
```

Now when I proceed to the final activity all I am seeing in the text view is the word Make.

```
    public class Direct extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.newthumb);

           Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();

            bundle.getFloat(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dirtext);
    textview.setText(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);



    }   
}
```

I am not getting any errors in debug and there hasn't been a single force close issue.   Is there something I am missing?  I've only been working with java for a couple weeks but this type of activity seems like it should be doable. (or I'm just an idiot)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bundle.getFloat(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE);` does not read anything. You are nowhere actually reading the Exif data from the image file. You simply are showing in the TextView the content of the static String named `ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE`.

The documentation is available: [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html). You will need to do something like:

```
ExifInterface exifReader = new ExifInterface(filename);
textview.setText(exifReader.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE));
```

Comment: Thanks Marvin.  I tried that the other night but I couldn't figure out how to declare a specific filename.